# Issue while running PPTP client on Windows 7

Tags: vpn, pptp

I am using the built-in Windows 7 pptp client to connect to some vpn server. The issue is - while it's connected, all my internet traffic goes through that connection, not just the network specific. It looks like when I try to go to any web site, it request to the vpn server first, which makes all my normal internet activity extremely slow

I recall that there was some setting in the Windows XP VPN client to only use vpn connection for that vpn network related traffic, but I can't find it in Windows 7 (maybe because I'm not sure what exactly I'm looking for).

Any help would be much appreciated, this problem is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to go into the VPN connection properties, go to the `Networking` tab, and double click (or use the Properties) button on the `Internet Protocol Vesion 4 (TCP/IPv4)`.  Hit the `Advanced` button, and uncheck the `Use default gateway on the remote network` option.

If your destination network is a little more complex, meaning that it has more than 1 subnet, this may cause you some problems unless you set up some custom routing rules.

Comment: That is it! Now I remember doing it on 20 computers at my past job 5 years ago ;) Thanks a bunch!